# How do I test if a file is writable (CLI)

Tags: dart, command-line-interface

I am taking my first steps in Dart today, and the first thing I am not sure about how to proceed is how to test whether a file that is passed as an argument to a CLI tool I'm writing is writable.

So the idea is that I have a tool that accepts an `input` directory and an output filename. What it does is parsing some files in the input directory, compiles the data into a meaningful JSON config and saves it in the `output` file.

However, before doing anything, I want to run a sanity check to see that the given output file argument can actually be used as a writable file.

The way I decided to solve this is by opening the file for Append in a try-catch block:

```
try {   
    new File(output).writeAsStringSync('', mode: FileMode.APPEND, flush: true);
} on FileSystemException catch(e) {
    // do something
}
```

However, I don't like this solution. Mainly that it creates a file if it doesn't already exist. Also, I don't see why I should write anything into a file when I just want to know whether it is writable or not.

What is the right way to do it in Dart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `file.statSync().mode` or `file.statSync().modeString()`. See [FileStat](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.21.0/dart-io/FileStat-class.html).

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. Without knowing if you are the owner or in a group, the mode is rather pointless.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite hard to do reliably in any language. As *Eiko* points out, knowing the file permissions is only half the story, since the current user, group and process determines how those permissions apply.

Some edge cases that can occur are:

- The file is writable when checked, but becomes unwritable by the time the writing needs to happen (e.g. another process changed the permissions).
- The file is not writable when checked, but becomes writable by the time the writing needs to happen.
- The file is write-only: it exists and is not readable, but can be written to.
- The file doesn't exist and the user/process is not permitted to create a new file in that directory.
- The file system has been mounted in read-only mode.
- The parent directory/directories don't exist.

So anything you write may produce false positives or false negatives.

Your method of appending nothing is a good simple test. It can be made more complicated to address some of the issues, but there will always be cases where the answer is not what you might want.

For example, if you don't like creating the file before the actual writing, test if it exists first:

```
bool isWritable;
final f = File(filename);
if (f.existsSync()) {
  try {
    // try appending nothing
    f.writeAsStringSync('', mode: FileMode.APPEND, flush: true);
    isWritable = true;
  } on FileSystemException {
    isWritable = false;
  }
} else {
  isWritable = ???; // do you prefer false positive or false negative
  // check if the parent directory exists?
}

// isWritable now, but might not be by the time writing happens
```

Or delete it after testing:

```
bool isWritable;
final f = File(filename);
final didExist = f.existsSync();
try {
  // try appending nothing
  f.writeAsStringSync('', mode: FileMode.APPEND, flush: true);
  isWritable = true;
  if (didExist) {
    f.deleteSync();
  }
} on FileSystemException {
  isWritable = false;
}

// isWritable now, but might not be by the time writing happens
```

Dart introduces an extra complication, with asynchronous code.

If using the `openWrite` method. It opens a stream, so any problems writing to the file are not raised when the file is opened. They occur later when using the stream or closing it, which can be far away from the file opening code where you want it detected. Or worse, it occurs in a different zone and cannot be caught.

One useful trick there is to open it twice. The first is used to detect if the file is writable when it is closed. The second is to obtain the stream that will be used for writing.

```
try {
  final f = File(filename);

  f.parent.createSync(recursive: true); // create parent(s) if they don't exist

  final tmp = f.openWrite(mode: FileMode.append);
  await tmp.flush();
  await tmp.close(); // errors from opening will be thrown at this point

  // Open it again

  sinkForWritingToTheFile = f.openWrite(mode: FileMode.append);

} on FileSystemException catch (e) {
  // exception from `close` will be caught here
  // exception from the second `openWrite` cannot be caught here
  ...
}
```